# Is telling about deprecated functionality wanted?

Tags: discussion

I often come along posts from users that  (obviously) just started programming in PHP that use the mysql extension. In the comments I frequently point out that they should stop using this extension and point them to to the part of the PHP documentation with more information.
Of course this is just one example, there are many more in any field of programming.

What I want to know, is it correct to warn people (especialy beginners)? And if so, are the comments the correct place?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171933/how-should-we-handle-ext-mysql-deprecation-in-php-questions-older-included

Comment: A comment mentioning it is definitely appropriate.  However just because something is deprecated does not mean that it doesn't work-  frequently deprecated just means "we decided this other way is better because our lead engineer likes it more" or "this method isn't how we envision you using us" rather than "this is really broken, never use this".  In the first 2 cases if you know what you're doing or if you have a codebase that porting would be expensive its absolutely ok to continue using it.

Comment: For PHP beginners, without a doubt it is correct to point this out and send them to the documentation. Very often, they are not even aware of the existence of "official documentation" because they work from tutorials.

Comment: It is of course not only the user that asks the question that benefits, also all the people that refer to the same question, who potentially are new programmers as well. (since usually the questions are also entry level).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's been debated here:  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171933/how-should-we-handle-ext-mysql-deprecation-in-php-questions-older-included

While I agree that we are polluting the comment space a bit with things unrelated to the question or problem at hand, at the same time I think it is worthwhile.

Reasons we should leave a comment:

- For questioners using `Mysql_` and are unaware of `Mysqli/PDO` but
  *would* be interested
- Anyone else coming to the question are made aware of `Mysqli/PDO`
- As a professional site offering top notch advice, and given that many
  users still seem to be using the depreciated `Mysql_` functions, I
  think it prudent and arguably in our duty to add such information for
  everyone to see, and on every question where `Mysql_` is used.

It should also be in any answer on a question which has `Mysql_` code, as answers are often linked directly, and comments might not be read, etc.
It also makes the answer more worthwhile as users should really be considering moving away from these depreciated functions, given that even cheap hosting companies are now on newer versions of PHP where said functions will no longer work.

I used to think it was all a bit noisy, but I realise that's because I see it on many PHP questions, but we should be offering advice on important things as that is why most users come here - to learn best practice. 
Even if not the lazy questioner with their crap code and no intention (or no ability) of switching away from `Mysql_`, other users might.

### When it becomes noise

The only problem is when there is more than one comment advising to use `Mysqli/PDO`, even if worded slightly differently, there is no need and then it becomes very noisy/spammy and I would imagine has adverse effects.
With one comment the user can take it or leave it, at worst ignore it, but when there's more than one comment users get frustrated because, after all said and done, it is not answering the question they came to get help with which we said we would do for them.

Perhaps on *valuable questions* which are not just localised to one users code, we could upvote the better comment advising on `Mysqli/PDO` and flag the others as not constructive.
To keep the question tidy but informative.

Answer (score 14):

It is generally correct to warn people that they are using deprecated functionality. If a user is posting an actual answer, they can point out this fact with their answer.

**In my opinion**, if a user is **only** pointing out that the functionality is deprecated but they are not actually tackling the issue raised in the question, they should post a comment.

Whenever pointing out that functionality is deprecated, support it with facts (e.g. a link to the documentation that states the functionality is deprecated). I've seen some instances where people were factually wrong.

Answer (score 5):

Certain functionality may be deprecated but it still exists.  So asking about it is definitely wanted.
After all, someone may be trying to remove the functionality from a system and needs to comprehend it thoroughly.  They may not necessarily be a beginner, just unfamiliar with the specific function - it happens to us all.

A good answer that explains the functionality will be useful to the community in the future.

Yes, responders should warn that the functionality is deprecated, either in the answer or in a comment.  That way we have assisted in cleaning up the world.